# "! Package amsmath Error: \begin{alignat} allowed only in paragraph mode.", what is this?

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, paragraphs, alignat

I'm encountering a issue with amsmath.

I'm trying to compile this code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
f\left(x\right) = ax^2 + bx + c \Leftrightarrow \left\{
\begin{alignat}{2}
&f\left(-2\right) = 3 \\
&f\left(1\right) = 6 \\
&f\left(2\right) = 15
\end{alignat}
\right.
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

And I have the following error:

```
! Package amsmath Error: \begin{alignat} allowed only in paragraph mode.
```

What's wrong?

Thanks and regards

Comment: please correct your title. There is no need to be rude.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! `alignat` is for display maths, and the `math` environment is for inline maths. Replave `alignat` with `alignedat`, or better with `cases`.

Comment: Hello, sorry for the title and thanks for your reply.
It's works now !

Comment: @MissingBracket Slangs are never welcome here, so I hope you understand the downvotes. I edited your question. And as I said in the comment of the answer, please add more content to your self-answer.

Comment: `f\left(x\right)` should be `f(x)` the `left-right` do nothing other than spoil the horizontal spacing here.

Answer (score 4):

As Bernard advised, I had just to replace `alignat` with `alignedat` to make it work in math mode.

Here is the working code:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\begin{math}
f\left(x\right) = ax^2 + bx + c \Leftrightarrow \left\{
\begin{alignedat}{2}
&f\left(-2\right) = 3 \\
&f\left(1\right) = 6 \\
&f\left(2\right) = 15
\end{alignedat}
\right.
\end{math}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A forgotten "$" before \begin{alignat} causes the same error message, e.g.:

```
$a \cdot b = c where:
\begin{alignat}{1}
c = d \cdot e
\end{alignat}
```

causes:

"! Package amsmath Error: \begin{alignat} allowed only in paragraph mode."

and the obvious fix is:

```
$a \cdot b = c$ where:
\begin{alignat}{1}
...
```